# Gradle afterResolve never called for Configuration

Tags: gradle

When I explicitly call `configurations.customConfig.resolve()` than `afterResolve` gets called, otherwise it never happens. Since I am telling Gradle not to cache changing modules I assumed `afterResolve` would be called every time. Even when I manually clean Gradle's cache `afterResolve` does not get called. Why?

```
configurations {
    customConfig
}

dependencies {
    customConfig('org.foo:foo:1.0') {
        changing = true
    }
}

configurations.customConfig {

    //make sure it will be resolved every time
    resolutionStrategy {
        cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
    }

    incoming.afterResolve {
        //never called
    }
}
```

Comment: Configurations typically aren't resolved until they are used. Doing something as simply as `gradle dependencies` however is typically enough to kick it off.